# Can't redefine service defined as constant

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, sinon

Here is my temp.js

```
angular.module('temp', [])
    .service('tempFactory', function() {
        this.a =10;
    });
```

and here is my temp.Spec.js

```
describe('temp', function() {
    var tempFactory;

    beforeEach(function() {
        var mockedTempFactory = {};

        module('temp', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('tempFactory', mockedTempFactory);
        });

        mockedTempFactory.a = 20;

        inject(function(_tempFactory_) {
            tempFactory = _tempFactory_;
        });
    });

it('console.log of a property', function() {
    console.log(tempFactory.a);
});
```

});

In console I get value of 20.

But if I define tempFactory like this:

```
angular.module('temp', [])
    .constant('tempFactory', {
        a: 10;
    });
```

In console I get value of 10.

Why can't I redefine tempFactory which was initially defined as constant, but can redefine tempFactory which was initially defined as service, value or factory?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create a **service**, you provide a constructor function to it

```
.service('tempFactory', function() {
    this.a = 10;
})
```

Angular then creates an instance of this function kinda like this:

```
var tempFactoryInstance = new tempFactory();
return tempFactoryInstance;
```

and returns back exactly that instance, so you could access the `a` property right away.

But the **constant** does not do anything, it just returnes what you've passed to it, so

```
.constant('tempFactory', function() {
    this.a = 10;
})
```

will just return a function back to you. If you want to be able to access the property `a` in this situation, then you have to "instantiate" it:

```
var instance = new tempFactory();
console.log(instance.a); // 10
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/crxB346Ezy8qCFGxVwGR?p=preview).

You can read more about the behavior of different provider [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Comment: I've corrected my example, now it is object, not function. Anyway I do not understand why I can redefine service, factory and value using value, but can not redefine constant using value method. And I can redefine constant using constant method.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I think the reason is in how these providers are created. If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/071be609275558f177cdb28d8f8891bd1805af1c/src/auto/injector.js#L687), you will see that `service` and `value` use `factory`, when `constant` is handled in a separate way.